# Can not install npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to make an smart mirror, before I decide to buy a Raspberry pi I want to preview it on my old computer.
I installed Raspberry pi (desktop version from homepage of Raspberry).
Everything was fine, When I install nodejs from apt source package, it doesn’t have alias (syntax for npm). Then I followed others topic, they said check uname -a and go to nodejs homepage to download a compatible version.

Here is mine `$uname -a Linux raspberry 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux`
Then I go to node homepage and download a version of Linux Binaries (ARM) V6 unpacked and copy all of them to `/usr/local/` and checked it with command `node -v` &`npm` -v. I got this error messages `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory`.

I thought that was my computer is not compatible but when I tried it on virtualbox I still got same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to install `gcc-6-arm-linux-gnueabihf`:

```
apt-get install gcc-6-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

That will provide the library file that is missing:

```
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
```

I recommend installing Node.js via this method instead of dumping the executables into `/usr/local`:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

You can leave off the `sudo` parts if you are running as `root`.

After that's done, you can run those commands with no issues (it's lowercase `-v` for the version).

```
node -v
npm -v
```